# How to determine that user finished vertical scrolling of tableview in objective c

Tags: objective-c, ios

I want to do some things when user finished vertical scrolling of table view. Does any body know how to determine that period?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your view controller to become a delegate of UIScrollView: `UIScrollViewDelegate`

In your delegate you can implement the following methods to help determine the end state:

```
- (void) scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

}
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate{

}
- (void) scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{

}
```

There are also two properties of UIScrollView that can help:

```
scrollView.isDragging
scrollView.isDecelerating
```

Just note that there are several end 'possibilities' for the scroll view.  If there is no deceleration, `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` won't be called, only `scrollViewDidEndDragging`.  However, if there is deceleration, both will be called.  You can use the `decelerate` var in `scrollViewDidEndDragging` to help determine when to execute your code.  For this reason, it's usually a good idea to have a separate method that's called by these delegate methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
@implementation YourViewController
{
    BOOL shouldDoYourTask;
}

-(void)performYourTask{
    //Do Your Stuff
    shouldDoYourTask = YES;
}

#pragma mark - ScrollView Delegate
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
                  willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
     if (!decelerate && shouldDoYourTask)
    {
        [self performYourTask];
        shouldDoYourTask = NO;
    }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (shouldDoYourTask) {
        [self performYourTask];
        shouldDoYourTask = NO;
    }

}
```